# Java software looks part Windows, part Metal

Tags: java, swing

[image]What I want is entirely `WindowsLookAndFeel`, and I have this code in my JFrame.

```
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, what I got it part Windows, part Metal (the cross platform style which looks awful. I think I know where the problem is:

The abnormal part(metal part) is a `JPanel`, and it is not originally built in the `JFrame`. I have a button. If pressed, the JPanel will be added to the JFrame.

```
    if (((JToggleButton) e.getSource()).isSelected()) {
        getContentPane().add(Console.getInstance(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    } else {
        remove(Console.getInstance());
    }
    revalidate();
    pack();
```

But still, I don't know why this happens, and how to solve it.

Comment: pics or didn't happen

Comment: @RooMan There you go. StackOverflow didn't support local pics upload. Now it does:)

Comment: Try  `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: @Frunk Thanks, but no difference. I used this originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the look and feel **outside** of the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Create a class having a main method. In that method set the LAF and then display the app:

```
try {
 UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
} catch(Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            jFrame.pack();
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: hit the nail on the head, man! I reckon I can use this trick sometimes, to have 2 lookAndFeel.

Comment: It doesn’t need to be outside the EDT. The only thing that matters is that you have to call it *before* creating Swing components. Otherwise you have to call [`updateUI()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#updateUI--) on all existing components or use [`updateComponentTreeUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#updateComponentTreeUI-java.awt.Component-) on the root of the component hierarchy. But switching the UI before creating the components is more reliable.